# `visual studio 2017 add as link content files (aspnetcore)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, msbuild, csproj

Since VS2017 returned to csproj, I am again able to add files "as link"... NOT!

When I link a file I also want it to be copied to the solution folder (not output directory, just solution), for example js files, webpack config files etc, I have them shared and "linked". But in order for these to be really "seen" by visual studio, I have to copy them to the solutions. I do this in a BeforeTargets="Build" event in the csProj file. That is how I did it before the project.json change (during the project.json period I just didnt do it at all).

But... what i find now it that when I re-open the solution, it says "linked file duplicated" and does not load the file. This is correct, since the file was copied during build. This USED TO WORK because previous web application csproj was declaratively listing all the filed in the project. Now it looks the directory and just add whatever's in there.
Any idea how to make this work again?

Sorry if it is not clear I can develop further but S.O wants me to keep questions short

thanks!

UPDATE: I've reinstalled VS 2017. Reproduced the case. Same error. I am now going to give you guys more detail:
1. I added a linked file and csproj did this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\..\..\Proyects\SomeProject\src\core.module.ts" Link="app\core\core.module.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

2. It shows in solution explorer:

[image]

3. I modify csproj to physically copy it to target folder. This resource is NOT a cs file but IT IS compiled. I need vs to be able to physically have it:

   < Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
   < Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
   < /Target>
4. Reload solution: "duplicated linked item".

A few more remarks: 
a. This happens on css files
b. With ts files... IT DOES NOT EVEN COPY THEM. Just ignores the copy completelly

Comment: You should be able to just include them in the project and if you select the properties of the link there should be a 'copy to output' option. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Hi! well... no. These files are typescript files shared among many projects. The TS files should be linked / visible in vs / copies to the project folder / NOT to the output (i don need to output these files.

Comment: If i do not add them tphisically to the project's folder, VS and webpack cannot compile them.... :'(

Comment: so why dont you add them physically and set it to do not copy to output again?

Comment: These files are linked. That is, I have a BASE project with many of my components, services, global stuff. If i make changes in "base", all other projects should change automatically. I have all sort of stuff in the base project ts, configuration files, views, etc. These files must be accesible to VS but only a few of them will make it to the output folder. Still, I need them to be linked, I believe

Comment: I have created a project and add a .js file as "add as link", then add a copy task in the .csproj to copy .js file to the solution folder, build the project, close and re-open it, but could not reproduce your issue. Would you mind sharing us more detail steps that we could reproduce that issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Leo, since my projects are in production, i had to roll back to vs 2015, I've uninstalled VS2017 (this caused a major headache for which i had to spend 2 full days fixing my vs2015 aspnetcore projects which stopped working for many many different causes). So I'm back in vs2015 where this is not possible. Do you happen to know if this is possible at all with the xproj model? Just sharing files between projects... it's all iwant...

Comment: @user5328504, do you mean that if possible share the files between Aspnetcore projects? As far as I know, the answer is yes. If you want to know more information, I suggest you could submit a new post which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. I will still glad to answer for you more detail.

Comment: no way to do it in 2015? I want back to 2015... Too much of a change for all my developers for such a small gain which was after all, included by microsoft with all the xproj/csproj thingy

Comment: @Leo-MSFT hi leo, please see my update! thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I pulled it off, but it is not nice.

First of all, lets understand what the problem was.
1. Add CONTENT (js, ts, css, images) files "as link"
2. Files need to be physically there. Why? In a classic web, you need those resources in the output directory, cause they're going to be needed only when running the app. Since mines is a webapi + angular app, I need to actually work a lot with these files and also they have to be available to my IDE physically. First of all, webpack needs to compile them, I have less and sass files that are also compiled. I also do chrome debugging... files need to be there... so you make a msbuild task to move files from their source location to your destination. Files must be copied again (if chenged) from their source. This is a standard practice, not a hack of myself
3. On reload, visual studio sees the links and tryes to (virtually) add them to project structure .**Now here's the problem... files are already there, cause you forced them to be there in point 2.**

**The reason why this works in 2015 is because csproj in 2015 does not inspect the folder structure to list its content. Files should be declarated in csproj in order to be in the project structure. Now 2017 uses a mix of csproj and the old "website" project, which would list the directory contents. Since vs 2017 "sees" the files, then it gets confussed when trying to add them...**

So my work around was to change my csproj in this way:

1. **Exclude the linked files** <-- this is what changed from vs2015
2. Add the linked filed
3. Copy the linked files

so it looks like this:
REMOVE

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="app\core\somefile.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

ADD.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\..\..\Projects\Core\somefile.ts">
      <Link>app\core\somefile.ts</Link>
    </None>
```

COPY ON BUILD

```
  <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(None.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%(None.Link)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" ContinueOnError="true" Condition="'%(None.Link)' != ''" />
  </Target>
```

I would also like to mention that I improved it a bit to be recursive so I dont end up with all references in there, so my point 2 actually looks like this:

```
<None Include="..\..\..\..\Projects\Core\**\*.*">
  <Link>app\Core\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
</None>
```

After many days of fighting with this I must say I am not 100% happy with the journey of csproj 2015 to xproj 2017 to csproj 2017. I think it was done with a good harth but they screwed a LOT of programmers with the way it was handled. I still love it, but it made me (and many others) suffer a lot and waste many many days in simmilar matters. This issue I faced was just one among many in a sea of documentation that goes obsolete, project name changes, and such.

Comment: Thank you very much, just spent a while trying to figure this out! Seems a bit hacky, but I don't see another alternative