# visual studio 2017 add as link content files (aspnetcore)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I have several webapi + angular project sharing a lot of typescript code. Therefore I want to link my files using "add as link" feature of visual studio.

The problem is it no longer works with the new csproj (nor with xproj, for that matter)

In this scenario, When I link a file I also want it to be copied to the solution folder (not output directory, it should be visible in solution explorer and visible for webpack!), for example js files, webpack config files etc, I have them shared and "linked". But in order for these to be really "seen" by visual studio, I have to copy them to the solution's tree. I do this in a BeforeTargets="Build" event in the csProj file. That is how I did it before the project.json change (during the project.json period I just didnt do it at all).

But... what i find now it that when I re-open the solution, it says "linked file duplicated" (or duplicated linked item) and does not load the file. This is correct, since the file was copied during build. This USED TO WORK because previous web application csproj was declaratively listing all the files in the project. Now it looks the directory and just add whatever's in there. Any idea how to make this work again?

Sorry if it is not clear I can develop further but S.O wants me to keep questions short

Answer (score 0):

Since this was a duplicated post of mine, I'll point to my answer to another question: [`visual studio 2017 add as link content files (aspnetcore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725958/visual-studio-2017-add-as-link-content-files-aspnetcore)